# Is it possible to improve this code to gain speed?

Tags: r

I write a R script and executed it on a dataframe with 16 variables and 1 000 000 obsevation but hasn't finished yet.

```
for(i in seq_along(cp.up$Connection.Number)){
if (nchar(cp.up$IMEI[i]) == 14){
  cp.up$IMEI.enrichi[i] <- substr(cp.up$IMEI[i], 1, 8)
} else if(nchar(cp.up$IMEI[i] == 13)){
  cp.up$IMEI.enrichi[i] <- substr(cp.up$IMEI[i], 1, 7)
} else {
  cp.up$IMEI.enrichi[i] <- NA
  }
}
```

The code works well because when I stopped the procedure, a part of the fataframe was full.

Thanks in advance !

Edit : the ifelse statement solve the problem,

```
chars <-nchar(cp.up$IMEI)
cp.up$IMEI.enrichi <- ifelse(chars == 14, substring(cp.up$IMEI, 1, 8),
                      ifelse(chars == 13,substring(cp.up$IMEI, 1, 7), NA))
```

Comment: what is cp.up? can you input data?

Comment: `sapply` won't speed up anything.

Comment: cp.up is a dataframe !

Comment: Try: `chars<-nchar(cp.up$IMEI);cp.up$IMEI.enrichi<-ifelse(chars %in% 13:14,substring(cp.up$IMEI,1,chars-6),NA)`

Comment: Why down vote a legitimate question ?

Comment: @MostafaRifi I didn't downvote, but some people might classify "improve my code for me" questions as "too broad" (one of the standard "close vote" reasons), especially if the person asking the question does not demonstrate their own attempt to improve the code.

Comment: $nrussell I inderstand. @nicola thank you very much, adapted your code to my problem and it works perfectly !! (I will edit my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many of your strings have lengths 13 and 14?  If it is only a few then it may be faster to start by filling your vector with `NA` then replacing those few values with the appropriate substrings:

```
cp.up$IMEI.enrichi <- NA
tmp.nchar <- nchar(cp.up$IMEI)
w1 <- which(tmp.nchar ==14)
cp.up$IMEI.enrichi[ w1 ] <- substr(cp.up$IMEI[w1], 1, 8)
w2 <- which(tmp.nchar == 13)
cp.up$IMEI.enrichi[ w2 ] <- sustr(cp.us$IMEI[w2], 1, 7)
```

This might even be faster when most of strings have 13 or 14 characters because you are taking advantage of the vectorized functions and not doing `if` comparisons in each iteration.

Another approach to look at if your computer has more than 1 core (or you have access to a computer with multiple cores that you could run this on, some of the cloud systems give you free hours to start which may more than cover what you would need for this) then look at the Rdsm package along with the parallel package for a way that you could have different cores filling in different parts of the data frame.  The pbd packages might work as well here, but I think the Rdsm approach may be simplest and quickest to get up and running.

Comment: Thank you greg, 6/10 strings have a length of 14, 3/10 have a length of 13 and 1/10 are NA. Your code is a little faster than $nicolas's response with ifelse statement. Thanks for your information.